# How I add attribute with product title in magento

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, custom-attributes

This is my code of title.phtml. Here I want to show attribute when I select dropdown value and hide when I didnot select any value from my attribute dropdown list.

Here in code I added span with class rx, I want to show attribute value in this code. My attribute code is also "rx"

Thanks in Advance

```
  <?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    
    /**
     * @var $block \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title
     */
    $cssClass = $block->getCssClass() ? ' ' . $block->getCssClass() : '';
    $titleHtml = '';
    if (trim($block->getPageHeading())) {
        $titleHtml = '<span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" '
            . $block->getAddBaseAttribute()
            . '>'
            . $block->escapeHtml($block->getPageHeading())
            . '</span>';
    }
    ?>
    <?php if ($titleHtml) : ?>
    <div class="page-title-wrapper<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($cssClass) ?>">
        <h1 class="page-title"
            <?php if ($block->getId()) : ?> id="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getId()) ?>" <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) : ?>
                aria-labelledby="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddBaseAttributeAria()) ?>"
            <?php endif; ?>>
            <?= /* @noEscape */ $titleHtml ?>
        
        <span class="rx">
        
        </span>
        </h1>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<sup>Rx</sup>
```